# Where in iPhone's Safari do you opt in to allow PWA installation from non-Safari browsers?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I saw here

https://firt.dev/notes/pwa-ios/

that iOS 16.4 allows you to install PWAs on non Safari browser but you have to opt in. I want to test this for my PWA, but cannot locate where to opt in.

Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't work with you having to opt in; it's an opt-in for the other browser. For instance, the Chrome app has to opt in and be approved by Apple. Only then will it be possible for you to use Chrome to install the PWA. The same thing applies to other browsers.

The last time I checked a few weeks ago to test my PWA, there were no browsers that had opted in and were ready so far.

Comment: Thanks for this, giviz. Who has to opt Chrome in - the user,  the developers of Chrome, or myself, please?

Comment: It's my understanding that Chrome developers have to opt in and then push the new version with the changes approved by Apple. However, information on the topic has been rather scarce so far.